# Facebook: The parameter app_id is required

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, login, facebook-api

resulta que estoy desarrollando una aplicación utilizando Xamarin para consumo en Android y bueno, el problema está al momento de querer autenticar mi app con Facebook, seguí este tutorial (usé el paquete **Xamarin.Auth**)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeoX1k7-1GE pero obtuve el siguiente error:

> [image: Primer error]
>
> No iniciaste sesión: No iniciaste sesión. Inicia sesión y vuelve a intentarlo.

Mas tarde continué buscando en Internet y ahora tengo lo siguiente:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>
> The parameter app_id is required

Estos son los métodos que utilicé para la petición

```
   private void FacebookLogin(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var autorizacion = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "1933406530283189",
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#"));

            autorizacion.Completed += FacebookAuth_Completed;
            var ui = autorizacion.GetUI(this);
            StartActivity(ui);

        }

        private async void FacebookAuth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var solicitud = new OAuth2Request(
                    "GET",
                    new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,birthday"),
                    null,
                    e.Account
                );

                var respuestafacebook = await solicitud.GetResponseAsync();
                var fbJson = respuestafacebook.GetResponseText();
                var fbUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cuenta>(fbJson);
                
                // var nombre = fbUser.Nombre;
                // var id = fbUser.Id;
            }
        }
```

PD. Ya he podido acceder pero se queda pasmado en esta parte:

> var respuestafacebook = await solicitud.GetResponseAsync();

Comment: prueba a añadir esto en tu manifest `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>` y en "values/strings" añade una clave que se llame `app_id` y como valor el id de tu app

Comment: Lo intenté y la app me quedó inutilizable, la verdad creo que es gracias a mi IDE o mi dispositivo, mañana intentaré con otros equipos, agradezco tu tiempo

Comment: debes ponerlo dentro de `<application>` pero fuera de `<activity>`.

Comment: Hola. Veo que te puede faltar el `accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token")`. En la configuración del `OAuthAuthenticator`. Al igual que `clientSecret`

Answer (score 1):

En la variable client_id debes asignar el app id de Facebook el cual supongo ya verificaste:

```
clientId: {app-id}
```

pero los valores de `AuthorizeUrl`  y  `RedirectUrl`  deben ser:

```
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/
```

y

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

Por lo tanto asignalos en tu método `FacebookLogin()` :

```
  private void FacebookLogin(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var autorizacion = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "1933406530283189",
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

            autorizacion.Completed += FacebookAuth_Completed;
            var ui = autorizacion.GetUI(this);
            StartActivity(ui);

        }
```